# Use requirejs and jquery, without clobbering global jquery?

Tags: jquery, module, requirejs

I'm using requirejs for the first time on a project. I'm working in an environment that has a lot of Javascript in place already, and I'm looking for clean ways to introduce my own code.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find a module of jQuery that I can load that doesn't clobber existing jQuery.

I was surprised that even require-jquery.js introduces a global version of jQuery. Is there a way to load jQuery as a module without introducing any globals?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

jQuery 1.7 supports AMD loading. But, the trick is avoiding a module naming conflict, since jQuery hardcodes its own module name as 'jquery'. If you are defining another module as 'jquery' (say, in the 'paths' property in your requirejs config), it will cause said conflict.

To load jQuery in your requirejs application scope, define a module, such as 'jquery-loader' and when you want to load jQuery, do it via 'jquery-loader':

```
define(['path/to/jquery.min'], function () {
    return jQuery.noConflict(true);
});
```

requirejs will 'cache' your reference to jQuery so that noConflict will only run the first time jquery-loader is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple versions of jQuery on one page is bad. Stop hacking and upgrade jQuery or use the older version.

As for keeping `$` safe try

```
(function($) {
    // requirejs inclusion block for loading


}(jQuery.noConflict(true));
```

If you pass `true` to `.noConflict` it will replace the old `jQuery` variable and not destroy that globally.

This means you can pass it in quietly. Say you have

```
<script src="jquery-1.2">
<script src="jquery-1.5">
```

Then using the above code would put the 1.2 `$` & `jQuery` back in global space and give you the 1.5 jQuery as a local `$` in your closure

Again I advise **AGAINTS** using multiple versions because its a right mess and a maintenance nightmare.

If your using 1.5 you can also use [`.sub`](http://api.jquery.com/sub/) to allow you to extend `jQuery` locally without corrupting the global `jQuery`

Comment: good advice against multiple versions ... but there are some cms plugins out there that come with packaged libraries. I've seen pages with 3+ jQuery/prototype versions mixed in by the cms - I wonder if there is a solution that comes near to YUI's versioning approach ...

Comment: There are valid reasons for needing this other than loading multiple versions on one page. If I am developing a 3rd-party JS app, it would be running in unknown environments. I need to dependably have the version of jQuery that I need without clobbering the consumer page.

Comment: @RamenRecon "Developing 3rd-party JS app" "requires jQuery" LOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOL.

Comment: @Raynos It's just a tool, like anything else. Guns don't kill people... and all that.

Comment: @RamenRecon increasing the size of your 3rd party application by 27kb is :\ its just ugh.

Comment: Cool. Go answer a question asking for your opinion on jQuery. Keep the answers on this question factual or keep it to yourself.

Comment: @RamenRecon ... Its a comment.

Comment: @Raynos if jQuery is already in the browsers cache (if You take it from google cdn) then You don't need to download it. Let's hope that many people use the cdn.

Answer (score -3):

load the jQuery script and then use `var myJ = jQuery.noConflict();`

or whatever shortcut variable you want

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries