# Make jQuery 1.7 and Require.js (and maybe Django) play nice, rationally?

Tags: jquery, django, requirejs

I've been having really weird path errors with jQuery and require.js (in combination with Django--both the dev server and apache).

The symptoms were that, as an example, I was defining modules that depended on jQuery (Going off of [an old tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/)) and jQuery was being loaded multiple times, with the last time leading to a 404, for example:

```
GET localhost:8000/static/js/lib/jquery.js
GET localhost:8000/static/js/lib/backbone.js
GET localhost:8000/js/lib/jQuery-1.7.1.js
```

Where Django's `STATIC_URL='/static/'`, and similar things happened where if I tried to use Apache and `collectstatic` jQuery would load once (or twice) and then would get re-loaded ignoring the static settings.

After seeing [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8735674/25616) about how named `define`'s suck, I tried just deleting the name from [jQuery's call to define](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/exports.js), so in my copy it looks like this:

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery ) {
define([], function () { return jQuery; } );
}
```

This seems to work, but it feels dirty.

All things considered, I could just use the jQuery/require.js bundle, but I don't feel safe assuming that it would handle upgrades well, or necessarily deal with my personal configuration, so I'd like to know if there is a "right way" to handle this mess.