# Two jQuery's one RequireJS

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I have a website that uses standard non-AMD javascripts and it has jQuery version "1.7.2". I am looking to move to using require.js I have a main file that looks like this.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "../components/jquery/jquery.min"
    }
});

require(["jquery"], function($) {
    console.log($().jquery;);
});
```

What I want to happen is for this to run and log (1.9.1) and for me to be able to run `console.log($().jquery;);` in the browser and get ""1.7.2". Meaning that all require dependancies utilize the new version but require itself doesn't mess with global scope. How can I make this happen?

In the build file for main I can see jQuery be included without being within any function. I expected it to be nested within a function preventing it from being in global scope.

I'm fine with even doing something like this

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: "../components/jquery/jquery.min"
  },
  shim: {
    jquery:{
      exports: "$JQ"
    }
  }
});

define("main", ["jquery"], function($JQ) {
  console.log($JQ().jquery);
});
```

But it's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

**Edit**:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "..components/jquery/jquery.min",
        jquery172: "../components/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min",
        jquery191: "../components/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min"
    }
});

// use jQuery 1.7.2 here
define("main", ["jquery172"], function($JQ) {
  console.log($JQ().jquery);
});


// use jQuery 1.9.1 here
define("some other module", ["jquery191"], function($JQ) {
  console.log($JQ().jquery);
});

// use whatevers global jQuery here
define("some other module", ["jquery"], function($JQ) {
  console.log($JQ().jquery);
});
```

Comment: This makes sense but there's one that's global and I don't wanna change that yet.

Comment: I have a copy of jquery that is not within require at all it is running on the page directly. I have require that has a new version. The new version in require happens to be global and it's breaking stuff on the site. I don't want require's new jquery to be global...

Comment: @ThomasReggi You'll have to use `jQuery.noConflict()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ so it doesn't muck up the global jQuery.

Comment: I've tried it and it's not working I found a simular question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858431/use-requirejs-and-jquery-without-clobbering-global-jquery

Comment: @ThomasReggi It makes sense to create a jQuery module to wrap it up `define(['path/to/jquery.min'], function () { return jQuery.noConflict(true); });`