# RequireJS - change jQuery module name

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have a file called "lib.jquery.js" (all libraries are starting with "lib." and not reusable application modules are starting with "app.") in my baseUrl directory, and a module definition:

```
define([
    "lib.jquery"
],
function(
    jQuery
){
    console.log(jQuery) // undefined
})
```

But jQuery here is undefined because jQuery module name is hardcoded inside it as "jquery" but not "lib.jquery". How do I configurate RequireJS correctly to make all loading modules check "lib.jquery" file when requesting "jquery" or force jQuery module to be named "lib.jquery"?

Answer (score 1):

The jquery script defines the module as 'jquery' and expects that you will simply reference it as 'jquery'. This is done because one should not load 2 jquery files of different versions.

Workaround would be put the `lib.*.js` files into a separate directory called `lib`.

```
define(['lib/jquery'], function (jQuery) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution here: [Use requirejs and jquery, without clobbering global jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858431/use-requirejs-and-jquery-without-clobbering-global-jquery/9593868#9593868)

1. Renamed file lib.jquery.js to lib.jquery-core.js
2. Created file lib.jquery.js with "jquery loader module":

   define(['lib.jquery-core'], function () {
       return jQuery.noConflict(true);
   });

Now it's working as intended to. Hardcoding names is evil.